# jquery ui draggable disables accordion keys

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-accordion

I have ajQuery UI accordion (latest version on Windows) and want to drag its entries to another accordion. Using draggable and droppable jQuery UI plugins it works without problems.

But as soon as I make the accordion draggable it loses all its key shortcuts (eg. RETURN to open/close entries) and also my hotkeys (added with `$('#accordion).keypress(func)`). This happens with Firefox and Chrome.

Is there a way to force draggable to not grab/disable the existing keypresses?

This fiddle show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mvalle/E3GDh/
You can click on the accordion headers to open/close entries and you can drag them (notice the cursor change). That's all. But if you remove the call to draggable you can open the accordion entries with RETURN and move between them with cursor arrows.

Thanks!

**UGLY WORKAROUND FOUND**

The problem seems due to the focus not returning to the accordion after the draggable creation, so the return key acts on whichever element has focus outside the accordion. At the price of a required mouse click on the accordion, the following two steps seem to solve the problem.

1) disable draggable on creation:

`$('#accordion').draggable({disabled: true, [other options...]})`

2) after draggable creation add (to re-enable it):

```
$("#accordion").mousedown(function() {
    $("#accordion").draggable({disabled: false})
})
```

Anyway, the core reason why this happens still escapes me.

Comment: 1) seems accordion does not receive focus (so keys do not work). 2) instead of removing draggable set it to {disabled:true}